# how to do a sinusoidal signal with frequency and amplitude

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

i need to create a sinusoidal signal with an amplitude of 5 cm and a frequency of 0.8 Hz.

please help

my code:

```
A=5;fs=0.8;
te=1/fs;
t=0:te:0.8;
s=A*sin(2*pi*fs*t);
plot(s,t)
```

when I plot, nothing comes out

Comment: Nothing comes out because `t` is empty.

Comment: Do `t = linspace(0,0.8,100);` Also: `plot(t,s)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest to you the following solution:

```
 f = 0.8;
 t = linspace(0,f,1000);
 a = 4;
 y = a*sin(2*pi*f*t);
 plot(t,y)
```

or

```
 function [ ] = singen(f, amp)
clf;

t = linspace(0,1/f,1000);

x=amp*sin(2*pi*f*t);

plot(t, x);
xlabel('Time (seconds)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
h = strcat({'Sinusoid of '}, num2str(freq), {'Hz with fs = '}, num2str(fs), {' Hz'});
title(h), grid on;
end
```